# How to install OS X on a Windows only Mac?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, install

I tried to use Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows on my MacBook Air. Long story short, due to installation issues, I wiped my MacBook Air drive.

I couldn't get my Mac to recognise a bootable disc of Yosemite made using [this guide](http://pureinfotech.com/2014/12/05/make-bootable-usb-mac-os-x-windows/). After some more fidling I managed to install Windows 7 on my Mac but now I need to find a way to install OS X.

Answer (score 2):

1. Turn your Mac off.
2. Turn it on, but hold down the Option key until you see images of two hard drives on screen.
3. Use the arrow keys to select "Recovery", press enter when you have selected it.

If you wish to erase Windows and your Windows data, if not, skip to step 9:

4. Click Disk Utility.
5. Click the partition under whatever your internal SSD is called, typically the brand name followed by some seemingly meaningless characters.
6. Select Erase in the toolbar
7. Confirm you wish to erase the drive
8. Upon completion of the wipe of your drive, close the window.
9. Select Install OS X and follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: This assumes that by 'wipe my drive' the OP didn't mean 'trash the entire thing', otherwise it's Cmd/R for [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201314)